Catching a Cat on an infinite Line
Upon entering a (very) large room, you are faced with an infinite line of cardboard boxes that are labeled, in order, by the nonnegative integers. In one of these boxes, a cat is hiding, but you do not know which one. Your task is to find the cat in this setup. To do that, you and the cat take turns like so:
Each turn, you may open any box and check if the cat is currently inside it. If it is, you win and the game ends here. Otherwise, you close the box again and leave the room for a moment. During your absence, the cat will move from its current hiding spot to any adjacent box (which may well be one that you have already checked, even just now). After that, you enter again and the game continues.
Can you find a strategy to always win this game?

Note that this is a strict logic puzzle, so solutions like "leave a camera in the room" are not intended.
If this was too easy for you, you may have fun trying your hand at the more challenging question (which is probably unsuited for this site though):

 What are the possible box layouts that allow you to win the game? Here, "box layout" is taken to sensibly mean any simple undirected graph without isolated vertices.

Have fun!

Do you have infinite turns? Also isn’t the answer just a trivial ‘yes’ of course there is a chance you can get lucky?

There is no turn limit, the game may continue indefinetely. (Though, to win you must of course catch the cat at some finite turn number.) I see that the wording is ambiguous, I will change it! :)

Why is the challenging question not suited for this site? See my answer. =D

This is a (semi)infinite version of the Princess in the Castle problem, which is also often asked using a fox or bunny in a row of holes.
Infinite is hard to deal with, so lets make it somewhat finite by assuming that the cat starts off somewhere within the first $n$ boxes. The following is a strategy for catching it.
I'll label the boxes starting from $1$, not starting from $0$ as the question states, so the cat starts off in one of the boxes $1$ to $n$. I'll also choose $n$ to be odd, as that makes things easier to explain.

 As with the standard finite solution, make a sweep by choosing the boxes $n-1$, $n-2$, ..., $2$. If the cat started off in a box with an even number below $n$ then this sweep will have caught it.
 If that sweep did not work, the cat must have started in a box with an odd number no larger than $n$. After those $n-2$ moves, the cat will now certainly be in an even-numbered box (since $n$ is odd), but it may have moved up to higher numbers. The furthest it could have gone is if it started at $n$ and did $n-2$ steps upwards into box $2n-2$. So now do a second sweep by choosing $2n-2$, $2n-1$, ..., $2$. This will then catch the cat.

 If the cat started off in one of the first $n$ boxes, then the above strategy catches it. If we did not catch it, then it did not start off within the first $n$ boxes, and we have just used up $3n-5$ moves searching for it.

Now we need to turn this into a strategy that works regardless of which number the cat starts at.

 You could repeat the above strategy using larger and larger $n$. However, you would need to let $n$ grow in larger and larger steps in such a way that even if the cat always moves to a higher box, it will not keep outrunning you. A simple way to ensure this is to just multiply $n$ by $9$ each time, as this keeps the number odd and this growth factor far outpaces the $3n-5$ used up moves that cat could use to try to escape.

 For example, let's just use $n=9^k$. After applying the strategy with $n=9$, we either catch the cat or know the cat did not start off in the first $9$ boxes. This takes $22$ moves.
 We then do the strategy with $n=81$. If we do not find the cat, it cannot have originally started off somewhere in the first $81-22=59$ boxes, and we have used a further $238$ moves to determine this.
 Then do the strategy with $n=729$. If we do not find the cat, it cannot have originally started off somewhere in the first $729-22-238=469$ boxes, and we have used a further $2182$ moves to determine this.
 And so on. Clearly, the number of eliminated starting boxes increases without bound, so the cat will eventually be found.


Well done! Since you posted a bit earlier and your strategy is a bit more explicit, I will give you the mark

Nobody has yet answered the final question, which is the most interesting part...
The cat can circumvent capture on any graph with a doubly-infinite chain or a cycle of length at least 3 or size-3 claw (i.e. a vertex connected to 3 disjoint chains of length 3 as shown below):
O
│
O
│
O
│
O ── O ── O ── O
│
O
│
O
│
O

or a size-2 fuzz ball (i.e. a vertex connected to infinitely many disjoint chains of length 2) or uncountably many unconnected edges. [I missed the last two cases in my first attempt.] (I'm assuming the natural version where the cat gets caught if it starts in an isolated vertex.)
~ ~ ~
I will use a lemma that to show escape it suffices to show that there is some finite k less than the subgraph size such that for every set S of k distinct vertices the set of neighbours of S has size at least k+1. [In my first attempt I also failed to realize this, and my argument is invalid for infinite k.] Assume some enumeration of the vertices of the subgraph. Let L[1] be k vertices in the subgraph excluding the vertex tested in step 1. Let L[t+1] be the first k vertices in the subgraph excluding the vertex tested in step t+1 that are neighbours of L[t]. I claim that there is an infinite path whose t-th vertex is in L[t]. Create a tree T whose root has children { (1,v) : v∈L[1] }, and whose every node (t,v) has children { (t+1,w) : v,w are neighbours and w∈L[t+1] }. Then T is finite-branching but infinite and hence has an infinite path by WKL.
The lemma extends as follows: It suffices to find a classification of sets of vertices as good or bad, such that the empty set is bad, and there is a finite good set, and for every finite good set S and vertex v, there is a finite good set S' of neighbours of S that excludes v. The proof is basically the same; every level is non-empty so we have an infinite tree with finite-branching and hence it has an infinite path.
It is easy for a doubly-infinite chain or a cycle of length at least 3. Every set of 2 vertices has at least 3 neighbours.
For a size-3 claw, the invariant (good set criterion) is a bit harder to find. View the graph as 1 central vertex plus 3 arms each with 3 vertices, and let the value of a vertex be 4 minus its distance from the centre, and let the value of each arm be the maximum value of a vertex at which the cat can be but 0 if there is none, and let the value of the centre be 4 if the cat can be there but 0 otherwise. The invariant is simply that the total value of the arms and centre is at least 4. There are two cases:

If the cat can be at the centre, then on the next step it can be at 3 vertices in different arms each with value 3, and you can eliminate at most 1 of them.
If the cat cannot be at the centre, then there must be at least 2 arms with positive value, so there must be arms with value combination (3,≥1) or (2,2) or (2,1,1). For (3,≥1), you must test in the centre on the next step, so those arms will have resulting values (2,≥2). For (2,2), no matter where you test the result is (3,≥1). For (2,1,1), the result is either (3,2,?) or (?,2,2).

For a size-2 fuzz ball, the lemma seems too weak, but here is a strategy for the cat:

If after the first k steps we keep testing the centre at least every odd step or every even step, then the cat starts in a chain that is never tested within the first k steps at the appropriate vertex such that after the first k steps the cat can go to the centre exactly every other step. This may not work because we may test the centre on some steps of the opposite parity as well, but the cat can modify its path to evade. If we eventually keep testing the centre every single step, then the cat simply stays in some chain that is never tested. Otherwise the cat can repeatedly return to the centre, and in-between those times it can go to some chain that will not be tested until the next return to the centre.
If we repeatedly deviate from same-parity testing of the centre, then the cat starts from the centre and does the following including one extra move before the first test: Let t be the next step at which we do not test the centre and the cat can be at the centre (by step parity), which exists since we must repeatedly perform non-centre testing, which must also have repeatedly changing step parity. Then the cat simply goes to some chain that will not be tested until step t and returns to the centre only at step t.

For uncountably many unconnected edges, the cat can trivially stay in an edge whose endpoints are never tested.
~ ~ ~
It is not too hard to figure out how to catch the cat if the graph does not have any of the above kinds of subgraphs. Consider the simple case where there is only one component, and let C be the longest chain in it.
If C is finite, then for each parity, sweep C from one end to the other, stopping at each vertex with side-groups (which hang off C) of depth at least 2 to clear those side-groups. Such side-groups have depth exactly 2 otherwise there would be a size-3 claw, and there are finitely many of them otherwise there would be a size-2 fuzz ball. To clear them out, we alternate between the vertex and the neighbours one by one.
If C is (singly-)infinite, then we repeatedly sweep towards its single end, each time starting from a sufficiently far point so that we can catch the cat no matter how far it started from the end.
If there is more than one component, then there are countably many non-singleton components, otherwise there would be uncountably many unconnected edges, so we sweep these components in a manner that ensures that we sweep each of them infinitely often. For example, we could sweep in rounds, where in round k we sweep the first k non-singleton components, each time choosing a sufficiently far starting point.
How far is sufficient? One way is as follows: For the k-th sweep of each component, which we start on step t, start the sweep at a point such that we can catch the cat if it is currently within distance t+k from the end. This implies that the k-th sweep would catch the cat if at the beginning of the whole game it was within distance k from the end.

Nice work! But I'm afraid, this is still a fair bit from the characterization. For one thing, can you win the game on an uncountable number of disjoint edges? :) There is also another (more interesting) forbidden subgraph, which I will not spoil here. But please keep at it, this is good work so far :)

But that is a nice (sketch of an) argument for the "long Y" graph - I prefer that to my own solution :)

@TimSeifert: In my mental model, everything is countable. XD Actually that made me forget about the uncountable case. Naturally, we can't win on any uncountable graph. By "forbidden" you mean that the cat cannot be caught on a graph that I somehow missed? Can you tell me the first sentence in my last 2 paragraphs that is wrong?

Well, there are some uncountable graphs that are easily won (a star of uncountable degree is won in two turns), so the cardinality restriction is more subtle :) Starting from "If C is finite ..." in the answer, your logic is faulty :)

@TimSeifert: Oops yes I did think of the star at the start but forgot later. As for the sweep logic, I'm sure that every side-chain has length at most 2 (otherwise there is a "long Y"). I'm also pretty sure that we can clear them all out. Just keep alternating between the vertex v on C and a vertex next to C in a side-chain, until all side-chains joined to v are cleared. Parity works because there are no cycles. What am I missing? ("the longest chain" should be "a longest chain" but it doesn't affect anything.)

Well, your strategy does not really adress the possibility of infinitely many side chains on a vertex in C. At the very least, it will certainly not work if there is such a vertex in the middle of C!

@TimSeifert: Oops!!! Argh.. From "finite C" I went to "finite everything". Sorry about that. I'll find a fix (for my post) now! =)

@TimSeifert: I have hopefully fixed my solution! Please let me know if you spot any remaining errors! =)

I think it looks good now, well done! Although I feel that employing WKL is a bit of a nuke - all of these forbidden subgraphs have fairly explicit (but a bit tricky for the 3-claw!) evasion strategies without employing any choice principle. Nonetheless, very good work!
If you want one last fun challenge: How about if you are allowed to have a go at this game twice with the cat starting in the same spot each time? Does the answer change? How so? :)

@TimSeifert: I'm not sure, but certainly we can catch the cat on the fuzz ball, and even a fuzz ball with a length-3 tail. But not a fuzz ball with 2 tails!

First, let's simplify the problem. Suppose that

 the room contains $n$ boxes coloured in a checkerboard pattern, and the cat must first hide in a box that has the same color as the last box.

The puzzle would then be easy to solve:

 Check every box from box $n$ to box $1$. Since two adjacent boxes don't have the same color, the cat will never be able to slip away from us and will eventually be caught.

To solve the actual puzzle, we just need to

 try for different values of $n$ that are sufficiently far apart from each other so we have the time to check boxes $n$ to $1$ without letting the cat run to infinity. Each time you start with a new $n$ value, you change your hypothesis about the color of the box in which the cat started. This will at some time bring us back to the finite case with the correct color parity, which ensures a win.


Well done finding the solution! Since there are two, I (somewhat arbitrarily) decided to go with the first one, but still, good work!

That’s fair! I was slower posting my answer and the other one is a bit more rigorous. Nice puzzle :)

The main problem we must contend with is that

 the cat can run off to infinity, and we can't chase it fast enough to rule out every box along the way.

Instead, we can

 pick some sequence $a_n$ that grows sufficiently fast ($4^n$ should suffice) and let those numbers be the starting points from which we travel back to box 1, checking every box twice along the way.
 You can see that we'll start from box 4 the first time, start from box 16 after 8 checks, start from box 64 after 40 checks,  start from box 256 after 168 checks, and so on.
 Since the box number increases faster than the number of checks we do before we reach that box, there will be some point at which we are further along than the cat,  no matter where it starts or how far it progresses. Once that happens, checking each box twice ensures that the cat cannot slip past us as we travel down the numbers, until we eventually trap it in box 1 and catch it.


Can you elaborate about how "checking each box twice ensures the cat cannot slip past us"? The cat could be in box n-1 when you're checking box n for the second time and then move to box n when you're going for box n-1.

There are some good thoughts here, but as already noted, the cat may (easily) slip through your net with this strategy.
